# Multiple $http requests in Ionic2 with interval

Tags: http, ionic2, observable, intervals

I want to fork multiple http requests into one observable, call it by interval and share same data between all subscribers.

My code looks like this so far:

```
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Rx";

let obs = Observable
    .interval(10000)
    .publish()
    .connect()
    .forkJoin(
      this.http.get(API_URL + "x", {headers: this.headers})
        .map(response => response.json()),
      this.http.get(API_URL + "y", {headers: this.headers})
        .map(response => response.json())
    )
    .map(res => {
     // do some stuff
     return res;
    });
```

Error:

```
Typescript Error
Property 'forkJoin' does not exist on type 'Subscription'.
```

I've read:

https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/16/cold-vs-hot-observables.html

[Multiple $http requests in Ionic2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38842832/multiple-http-requests-in-ionic2)

http://restlet.com/blog/2016/04/12/interacting-efficiently-with-a-restful-service-with-angular2-and-rxjs-part-2/

Thanks!

Comment: did you try without `publish()` and `connect()`?

Comment: Results into this error:  Property 'forkJoin' does not exist on type 'Observable<number>'.

Comment: at least you have an Observable instead of a Subscription. Maybe you'll find an answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38443798/property-forkjoin-does-not-exist-on-type-typeof-observable-angular2

Comment: I tried all hints given in that link but nothing helped. I tried to update to rxjs 5.0.3 but same result. Reverting to 5.0.0-beta.12

Comment: `forkJoin` is a static Observable method... You should call it with `Rx.Observable.forkJoin(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
let source = Observable
    .interval(1000)
    .flatMap(() => {
        return Rx.Observable.forkJoin(
            this.http.get(API_URL + "x", {headers: this.headers})
                .map(response => response.json()),
            this.http.get(API_URL + "y", {headers: this.headers})
                .map(response => response.json())
        )
    })
    .publish();

source.connect();
```

Then Observers subscribe to this observable

```
source.subscribe(...);
```

What I'm doing here is to take the interval observable and replace each value for a forkJoin of all operations. Then publishing it to share the same data to many subscriptions.

Another issue you had in your implementation is that you were returning the Subscription from `.connect()`, that's just meant to dispose it (unsubscribe) whenever you need it. Observers should subscribe to the published source.

Comment: Thank you! It's working! In my case, I had to replace "Rx.Observable.forkJoin" with "Observable.forkJoin". Thanks for the great explanation ;)